# How to keep data in additionally added input fields after post

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have am html-form with input fields and there is the possibility to create additional input fields on demand by using a javascript function. Here is the script that works perfect:

```
    <input id="myField0" name="myField[]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][0]) ? $_POST['myField'][0] : '' ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/><br>
    <input id="myField1" name="myField[]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][1]) ? $_POST['myField'][1] : '' ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/><br>
    <input id="myField2" name="myField[]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][2]) ? $_POST['myField'][2] : '' ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/><br>
    <input id="myField3" name="myField[]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][3]) ? $_POST['myField'][3] : '' ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/><br>

    <script>
    // Start function for additional input fields

    var counter = 5;
    var limit = 15;

    function addInput(divName){
         if (counter == limit)  {
        alert("You have reached the limit of " + counter  + " inputs");
       } else {
        // Create new div
        var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
        newdiv.innerHTML = '<br><input type="text" id="myField' + counter + '" name="myField[]" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/>';
        document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);

        // Re instantiate Awesomplete
        new Awesomplete(newdiv.querySelector('input'), { list: document.querySelector('#myList') });

        // Set counter
        counter++;
      }
     }

    // End function for additional input fields
    </script>

         <div id="dynamicInput">
         <b></b><input type="text" id="myField4" name="myField[]" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][4]) ? $_POST['myField'][4] : '' ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/>
         </div>
         <input type="button" id="additional_inputfield" value="Additional input field" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
```

Now, I want to keep the entered data in the input fields after sending the form. This works well with in the preexisting input fields, however, not in the additionally  created input fields since I can not use php in my javascript function. Is there any simple solution to keep the entered values in all fields?

Comment: You are going to have to be a bit more specific about what the issue is here

Comment: Are you submitting the form on the same page or another page?

Comment: how do you store the data ? are you looking for ajax calls ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, RiggsFolly, I´m sorry for obviously having not expressed myself very well! I have 5 pre-existing input fields (myField 0-4). If someone wants to enter more than 5 values, there is a button that creates an additional input field with every click. Usually, after post input fields are cleared. By using value="<?php echo isset($_POST['myField'][4]) ? $_POST['myField'][4] : '' ?>" I can keep the values in the fields. However, this only works in the pre-existing 5 fields and not in the additionally created ones.

Comment: The form is submitted on the same page. Unfortunately, I´m not very proficient with Ajax.

Comment: Then when you get the data posted to the script you know "how many extra fields were created" just add those to the form as you rebuild it

Comment: Is your problem solved or should I let you know the solution?

Comment: add a hidden field and increment its value on every field addition and then use this hidden field value after submitting the form to recreate all fields inside div#dynamicInput with their respective values. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you user1544541! This is an interesting approach, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of possible solutions, from rendering the form server side, to rebuilding it with javascript, based on some data dumped from php into a script tag.

As your javascript seems to be only dom manipulation, not data backed (angularjs, vuejs etc) then the 1st option is probably the easiest:

```
$inputCount = 4; //default

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
     $inputCount = count($_POST['myfield']); //set count to number of posted fields
}
//create as many inputs as required.
for($i=0; $i<=$inputCount; $i++):?>

    <input id="myField<?= $i; ?>" name="myField[]" value="<?= isset($_POST['myField'][$i]) ? $_POST['myField'][$i] : ''; ?>" class="awesomplete" list="myList" size="32"/><br>

<?php endfor;>

<script>
// Start function for additional input fields
var counter = <?=$inputCount +1;?>;
//the rest of your code
```

Note i have used the php short echo tag `<?=` in place of `<?php echo` as a personal preference, they are functionally the same

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, it works! I only wonder, why the number of input fields increases by 2 after every post? One field more is caused by the line in the dynamicInput div. But the second? When I set $inputCount = count($_POST['myfield']) - 2; I get the right number of fields.